# How to make filter criteria fieldset in a view to be collapsible by clicking on a link using tpl file overriding default file?

Tags: 7, theming, views

I am trying to create a collapsible fieldset of filter criteria on click of a link 
the code I tried is as follows:
    ';
    ?>

```
<fieldset class="collapsible collapsed">
<legend class="collapse-processed">
<a href="#">Error : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'drupalGetSummary' jquery.min.js:16</a>
<a href="#">Edit Search Criteria</a>
</legend>
<fieldset>
```

But when I click on the link I dont get the collapsed or collapsible feature

The error I am getting is as follows:
**Error : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'drupalGetSummary' jquery.min.js:16**

In the resources of the page the collapse.js is present which indicates that the js  file is loaded.

After updating the jquery version from 1.5 to 1.7 the old error disappears and new error is displayed as follows: 
**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'drupalGetSummary' collapse.js:70**

Comment: updated the answer pls check

Comment: as far as I remember misc/collapse.js is the js that drupal uses for collapsible fieldset, check if you are getting any js error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the above working by writing a function in the module as shown in the [link](http://dropbucket.org/node/220)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_view().
 */
function my_module_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['view']->name === 'my_view') {
    // Wrap exposed filters in a fieldset.
    if ($vars['exposed']) {
      drupal_add_js('misc/form.js');
      drupal_add_js('misc/collapse.js');
      // Default collapsed
      $collapsed = TRUE;
      $class = array('collapsible', 'collapsed');
      if (count($_GET) > 1){
        // assume other get vars are exposed filters, so expand fieldset
        // to show applied filters
        $collapsed = FALSE;

    $class = array('collapsible');
  }
  $fieldset['element'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Refine your search',
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => $collapsed,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => $class),
    '#children' => $vars['exposed'],
  );
  $vars['exposed'] = theme('fieldset', $fieldset);
}
  }
}
```

Comment: correct me if i am wrong but it will work only when ajax is disabled in views.

Answer (score 0):

This happened often because collapse js files not loaded there,mybe by adding the js library it get work

Try this

```
drupal_add_js('misc/form.js');
drupal_add_js('misc/collapse.js');
```

or

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.collapse');
```

Comment: i have added (misc/collapse.js'); but still it does not works

Comment: pls help should i add drupal.collapse?

Comment: first look up collapse.js in loaded script in browser source, if it is not loaded try to load it with form.js. they need to collapse work

Comment: Error : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'drupalGetSummary' jquery.min.js:16

Comment: as you know jquery error sometimes disrupt js jobs.maybe it be the source of problem,update your jquery,do you install jquery update module? if yes go to settings of it and try another versions

Comment: ok i will update jquery and let u know if the error has disappeared

Comment: Pls help . I have updated the jquery to 1.7 version but now the error shown is as follows :                       Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'drupalGetSummary' collapse.js:70